Animation froze midway through animation in unity 3d
This occured after I had finished all the movement and animation in unity for this. Just midway through the animation you have your player running in a weird way with his leg up and other leg diagnol continuous. Everything about the movement is fine it is just the animation that is stuck up.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;
using Quaternion = UnityEngine.Quaternion;
using Vector3 = UnityEngine.Vector3;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float turnSmoothTime = .1f;

    private float turnSmoothVelocity;
    public float walkSpeed;
    public float sprintSpeed;
    private float trueSpeed;
    public Transform cam;
    public float jumpHeight;
    public float gravity;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    public Animator anim;
    public bool sprinting;
    private void Start()
    {
        trueSpeed = walkSpeed;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, .1f, 1);
        anim.SetBool("isGrounded", isGrounded);
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -1;
        }
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            trueSpeed = sprintSpeed;
            sprinting = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            trueSpeed = walkSpeed;
            sprinting = false;
        }

        anim.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        anim.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        if (direction.magnitude >= .1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = MathF.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity,
                turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir * trueSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            if (sprinting)
            {
                anim.SetFloat("Speed", 2);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetFloat("Speed", 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetFloat("Speed", 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt((jumpHeight * 10) * -2f * gravity);
        }

        if (velocity.y > -20)
        {
            velocity.y += (gravity*10) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

I tried resetting the whole thing restarting the whole project... Same result. I used tutorials but still nothing.

I think your velocity should be 0 when on ground
if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0){velocity.y = 0;}

Also, can you play your animation and check if it is correct... ensure it is a looped animation
